# KendoGrid sorting number as string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid that is not sorting numbers correcting; they are sorting as strings and not numbers. So with a sorted column of numbers, 1 through 10, instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, I end up with 1,10,2,3, etc..

The data provided to the grid is a JSON array. The column I am trying to sort on is the Id column below. I have tried and had success using a different definition, where the data is pulled directly from the server and the sorting is done on the server; however I am not able to do so in this case.

My html is:

```
<div id="myGrid" kendo-grid="myGrid"
k-options="myGridOptions"></div>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
var myModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "Id",
    fields: $scope.myColumns
});

$scope.myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: $scope.data,
    pageSize: 10,
    sort: [{field:"Id", dir:"asc"}],
    schema: {
        model: myModel
    }
});

$scope.myColumns    = [
{ field: 'Id',title: 'ID',width:"80px", type:"number" },
{ field: 'amount',title: 'Amount',width:"130px",type:"number" }
                      ];

$scope.myGridOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.myDataSource,
    reorderable: true,
    groupable: false,
    sortable: {
        allowUnsort: false,
    },
    selectable: "multiple, row",
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 20, 
        pageSizes: [10, 20, 50], 
    },
    columns: $scope.myColumns,
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `schema.model.fields` can be defined as an array.

Try this:

```
var myModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "Id",
    fields: { Id: { type:"number" }, amount: { type: "number" } }
});
```

See http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I made this change and it did not correct the issue.

Comment: Is your column of type number in the data you have?

Comment: An example of the Id field in the data I am seeing is "Id":"1", should it be "Id": 1 with out the quotes around the 1?

Comment: Yes. The best way is to have your data directly in the correct format rather than converting it using Kendo. It should be  `"Id":1`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.